# MobileFirst: Server to send update notification/message to clients

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Is it possible that MobileFirst Server push some update to all clients when specific change has occurred or specific user did some action?

For example, an admin opened a session for all other users to join in. So once admin opened a session then instantly other should be notified of this and can see the option/button to join the session.

or, admin wants to send a message to all connected users.

Here I dont want to use database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature.

The closest feature is the Remote Notify feature in the MFP Console, that enables you to send a message to all applications from a specific environment/environment version.

This message displays only once per a message life cycle, when the application first connects to the MFP Server. It will display again only if you will set it again in the console.

You could also `localStorage.removeItem("messageId");` in wlCommonInit so that it will be displayed on each startup of the application.